# Scatterplot with edgeR DESeq Voom

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am new in RNAseq and I started using edgeR, DESeq and Voom from Limma package to do differential analysis.

I have a data frame of 30 couples of Normal and Tumoral tissues

Since each method is different and gives different results I would like to do a scatterplot of each couple according to the method I use. I would like to plot the data exactly used to do the test.

Is there a way to do this for each of the 3 methods and if yes how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DESeq2 has a function to plot exactly what you are looking for (see the section 6 of the manual):

```
par( mfrow = c( 1, 2 ) )
plot( log2( 1+counts(dds, normalized=TRUE)[, 1:2] ), col="#00000020", pch=20, cex=0.3 )
```

Another option is to export the data from each package as csv use to make the plots to compare the methods. You can use the lattice package to make the plots. Below is an example that you can run and see how to set up your data frame to plot it.

```
#To do for one package at time:
attach(mtcars)
plot(wt, mpg, main="Scatterplot Example", 
    xlab="Car Weight ", ylab="Miles Per Gallon ", pch=19)

# Scatterplot Matrices from the lattice Package -  to compare all 3 packages 
library(lattice)
splom(mtcars[c(1,3,5,6)], groups=cyl, data=mtcars,
    panel=panel.superpose, 
   key=list(title="Three Cylinder Options",
   columns=3,
   points=list(pch=super.sym$pch[1:3],
   col=super.sym$col[1:3]),
   text=list(c("4 Cylinder","6 Cylinder","8 Cylinder"))))
```

This are only examples. If you have your data or a sample dataset, you can share it and it will be easier to explain how to plot it.